# npm ERR! - Ao executar algum comando na aplicação

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm

Estava com a aplicação em NodeJS funcionando normalmente, porém agora ele inicia a aplicação. Mas quando executo qualquer comando ele apresenta esse erro.
Estou usando o Sqlite3.

> npm ERR! Windows_NT 10.0.15063
>
> npm ERR! argv "C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe" "C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\bin\npm-cli.js" "start"
>
> npm ERR! node v6.11.2
>
> npm ERR! npm  v3.10.10
>
> npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
>
> npm ERR! stcprest_node@1.0.0 start: `node app.js -ns -p 8888`
>
> npm ERR! Exit status 3221225477
>
> npm ERR!
>
> npm ERR! Failed at the stcprest_node@1.0.0 start script 'node app.js -ns -p 8888'.
>
> npm ERR! Make sure you have the latest version of node.js and npm installed.
>
> npm ERR! If you do, this is most likely a problem with the stcprest_node package,
>
> npm ERR! not with npm itself.
>
> npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
>
> npm ERR!     node app.js -ns -p 8888
>
> npm ERR! You can get information on how to open an issue for this project with:
>
> npm ERR!     npm bugs stcprest_node
>
> npm ERR! Or if that isn't available, you can get their info via:
>
> npm ERR!     npm owner ls stcprest_node
>
> npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.
>
> npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
>
> npm ERR!     C:\Users\lucas\Desenv\DefaultCollection\STCPRestNode\npm-debug.log

Segue o npm-debug.log

> 0 info it worked if it ends with ok
>
> 1 verbose cli [ 'C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe',
>
> 1 verbose cli   'C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\bin\npm-cli.js',
>
> 1 verbose cli   'start' ]
>
> 2 info using npm@3.10.10
>
> 3 info using node@v6.11.2
>
> 4 verbose run-script [ 'prestart', 'start', 'poststart' ]
>
> 5 info lifecycle stcprest_node@1.0.0~prestart: stcprest_node@1.0.0
>
> 6 silly lifecycle stcprest_node@1.0.0~prestart: no script for prestart, continuing
>
> 7 info lifecycle stcprest_node@1.0.0~start: stcprest_node@1.0.0
>
> 8 verbose lifecycle stcprest_node@1.0.0~start: unsafe-perm in lifecycle true
>
> 9 verbose lifecycle stcprest_node@1.0.0~start: PATH: C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\bin\node-gyp-bin;C:\Users\lucas\Desenv\DefaultCollection\STCPRestNode\node_modules.bin;C:\Users\lucas\bin;C:\Program Files\Git\mingw64\bin;C:\Program Files\Git\usr\local\bin;C:\Program Files\Git\usr\bin;C:\Program Files\Git\usr\bin;C:\Program Files\Git\mingw64\bin;C:\Program Files\Git\usr\bin;C:\Users\lucas\bin;C:\Oracle\instantclient;C:\Python27;C:\Python27\Scripts;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0;C:\Program Files\nodejs;C:\Program Files\Microsoft VS Code;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\130\Tools\Binn;C:\Program Files\dotnet;C:\Program Files\Git\cmd;C:\Users\lucas\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps;C:\Program Files\Git\usr\bin\vendor_perl;C:\Program Files\Git\usr\bin\core_perl
>
> 10 verbose lifecycle stcprest_node@1.0.0~start: CWD: C:\Users\lucas\Desenv\DefaultCollection\STCPRestNode
>
> 11 silly lifecycle stcprest_node@1.0.0~start: Args: [ '/d /s /c', 'node app.js -ns -p 8888' ]
>
> 12 silly lifecycle stcprest_node@1.0.0~start: Returned: code: 3221225477  signal: null
>
> 13 info lifecycle stcprest_node@1.0.0~start: Failed to exec start script
>
> 14 verbose stack Error: stcprest_node@1.0.0 start: `node app.js -ns -p 8888`
>
> 14 verbose stack Exit status 3221225477
>
> 14 verbose stack     at EventEmitter. (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\lib\utils\lifecycle.js:255:16)
>
> 14 verbose stack     at emitTwo (events.js:106:13)
>
> 14 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.emit (events.js:191:7)
>
> 14 verbose stack     at ChildProcess. (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\lib\utils\spawn.js:40:14)
>
> 14 verbose stack     at emitTwo (events.js:106:13)
>
> 14 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:191:7)
>
> 14 verbose stack     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:891:16)
>
> 14 verbose stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:226:5)
>
> 15 verbose pkgid stcprest_node@1.0.0
>
> 16 verbose cwd C:\Users\lucas\Desenv\DefaultCollection\STCPRestNode
>
> 17 error Windows_NT 10.0.15063
>
> 18 error argv "C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe" "C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\bin\npm-cli.js" "start"
>
> 19 error node v6.11.2
>
> 20 error npm  v3.10.10
>
> 21 error code ELIFECYCLE
>
> 22 error stcprest_node@1.0.0 start: `node app.js -ns -p 8888`
>
> 22 error Exit status 3221225477
>
> 23 error Failed at the stcprest_node@1.0.0 start script 'node app.js -ns -p 8888'.
>
> 23 error Make sure you have the latest version of node.js and npm installed.
>
> 23 error If you do, this is most likely a problem with the stcprest_node package,
>
> 23 error not with npm itself.
>
> 23 error Tell the author that this fails on your system:
>
> 23 error     node app.js -ns -p 8888
>
> 23 error You can get information on how to open an issue for this project with:
>
> 23 error     npm bugs stcprest_node
>
> 23 error Or if that isn't available, you can get their info via:
>
> 23 error     npm owner ls stcprest_node
>
> 23 error There is likely additional logging output above.
>
> 24 verbose exit [ 1, true ]

Comment: Pode colocar a stack do npm_debug.log?

Comment: @FelipeAvelar acrescentei o arquivo que solicitou.

Comment: Você tá executando esse comando pelo cmd? Se sim, ele tem status de administrador?

Comment: É sim.. E tem permissão de administrador..